# How to convert FOREX Historical data from M1 to M2, M5 and M15 timeframes?

Tags: sql, excel, data-conversion, forex

I have several years of FOREX historical data, but it's listed minute by minute. I would like to know how do I do to convert it to M2, M5 and M15. I tried lots of things and methods, but none worked.

Excel functions or SQL scripts are welcome.

Below is listed a little sample of data format.

```
Date        Time    Open    High    Low     Close
2016.01.03  17:00   1.08701 1.08713 1.08701 1.08713
2016.01.03  17:01   1.08712 1.08712 1.08712 1.08712
2016.01.03  17:02   1.08708 1.08722 1.08708 1.08722
2016.01.03  17:03   1.08717 1.08723 1.08717 1.08723
2016.01.03  17:04   1.08718 1.08718 1.08711 1.08711
2016.01.03  17:05   1.08703 1.08716 1.08701 1.08712
2016.01.03  17:06   1.08721 1.08721 1.0871  1.0871
2016.01.03  17:07   1.08712 1.08715 1.08712 1.08712
2016.01.03  17:08   1.08711 1.0872  1.08711 1.08713
2016.01.03  17:09   1.08716 1.08723 1.08708 1.08708
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for M2.  It should be easy to see how to alter it for M5 and M15

```
declare @forexDate table
(
recDate datetime,
openVal float,
highVal float,
lowVal float,
closeVal float
)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:00', 1.08701, 1.08713, 1.08701, 1.08713)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:01', 1.08712, 1.08712, 1.08712, 1.08712)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:02', 1.08708, 1.08722, 1.08708, 1.08722)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:03', 1.08717, 1.08723, 1.08717, 1.08723)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:04', 1.08718, 1.08718, 1.08711, 1.08711)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:05', 1.08703, 1.08716, 1.08701, 1.08712)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:06', 1.08721, 1.08721, 1.0871,  1.0871)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:07', 1.08712, 1.08715, 1.08712, 1.08712)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:08', 1.08711, 1.0872, 1.08711, 1.08713)
INSERT INTO @forexDate VALUES('2016.01.03 17:09', 1.08716, 1.08723, 1.08708, 1.08708)

SELECT o.recDate, o.openVal, c.closeVal, mx.highVal, mn.lowVal FROM 
(SELECT recDate, openVal, highVal, lowVal, closeVal, 
CAST((RowNum + 1) / 2 as int) AS Batch, (RowNum + 1) % 2 AS BatchPos FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recDate) AS RowNum FROM @forexDate) x) o
inner join
(SELECT recDate, openVal, highVal, lowVal, closeVal, 
CAST((RowNum + 1) / 2 as int) AS Batch, (RowNum + 1) % 2 AS BatchPos FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recDate) AS RowNum FROM @forexDate) x) c
on o.Batch = c.Batch
inner join
(SELECT Batch, MAX(highVal) as highVal FROM
(SELECT recDate, openVal, highVal, lowVal, closeVal, 
CAST((RowNum + 1) / 2 as int) AS Batch, (RowNum + 1) % 2 AS BatchPos FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recDate) AS RowNum FROM @forexDate) x) mxpre GROUP BY Batch) mx
on mx.Batch = o.Batch
inner join
(SELECT Batch, MIN(lowVal) as lowVal FROM
(SELECT recDate, openVal, highVal, lowVal, closeVal, 
CAST((RowNum + 1) / 2 as int) AS Batch, (RowNum + 1) % 2 AS BatchPos FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recDate) AS RowNum FROM @forexDate) x) mnpre GROUP BY Batch) mn
on mn.Batch = o.Batch
WHERE o.BatchPos = 0 AND c.BatchPos = 1
```

The results should look like this:

```
recDate openVal closeVal    highVal lowVal
2016-01-03 17:00:00.000 1.08701 1.08712 1.08713 1.08701
2016-01-03 17:02:00.000 1.08708 1.08723 1.08723 1.08708
2016-01-03 17:04:00.000 1.08718 1.08712 1.08718 1.08701
2016-01-03 17:06:00.000 1.08721 1.08712 1.08721 1.0871
2016-01-03 17:08:00.000 1.08711 1.08708 1.08723 1.08708
```

I hope this is what you were after!

In practice you would want to insert the Batch and BatchPos pre-results into a temporary table and then do a series of self-joins, rather than everything on the fly as above!

Answer (score 1):

I think a PivotTable will do the work for you but since the 'automatic' choice of group size is restricted to days (I have no idea why) it would take a hack giving some results that would need careful interpretation, though changing the size of the grouping would be easy:

[image: SO44420634 example]

ColumnA has in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=INT(B2)-42372+MOD(B2,1)*60*24
```

The selected cell can be interpreted back into the start of the interval with a VLOOKUP as shown highlighted, but it would not be so simple for any ranges that start at a time for which there is no existing data point.

This takes the average of all available readings for each interval, not the first.